# How to replicate a foreign remote database into a local database? (CouchDB / MongoDB)

Tags: json, mongodb, couchdb, database-replication, database-mirroring

I would like to extend the data model of a remote database that is available via a [web service interface](http://data.wien.gv.at/katalog/baumkataster.html). Data can be requested via HTTP GET and is delivered as JSON ([example request](http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien%3aBAUMOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&maxfeatures=5)). Other formats are supported as well.

```
// URL of the example request.
http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien:BAUMOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&maxfeatures=5
```

First object of the JSON answer.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
       "id": "BAUMOGD.3390628",
       "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
             16.352910973544105,
             48.143425569989326
          ]
       },
       "geometry_name": "SHAPE",
       "properties": {
          "BAUMNUMMER": "1022 ",
          "GEBIET": "Strassen",
          "STRASSE": "Jochen-Rindt-Strasse",
          "ART": "Gleditsia triacanthos (Lederhülsenbaum)",
          "PFLANZJAHR": 1995,
          "STAMMUMFANG": 94,
          "KRONENDURCHMESSER": 9,
          "BAUMHOEHE": 11
       }
    },
...
```

My idea is to extend the data model (e.g. add a text field) on my own server and therefore mirror the database somehow. I stumbled into [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and its document-based architecture which feels suitable to handle those aforementioned JSON objects. Now, I ask for advise on how to replicate the foreign database **initially** and on a **regularly** basis.

Do you think CouchDB is a good choice? I also thought about [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). If possible, I would like to avoid building a full Rails backend to setup the replication. What do you recommend?

Comment: CouchDB does replication out of the box and uses a simple REST API. That being said I love MongoDB, but I imagine it will be a little fancier to sync up your models.

Comment: You don't own the remote db, do you?

Comment: @JamundFerguson I saw the replication feature in CouchDB. How would you setup a the replication with the particular example? Please be more descriptive.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, I do not own the remove database. All I can access is their public API / web service interface.

Comment: Replication can be set up only between two CouchDB instances. Not between a CouchDB and some 3rd-party web service.

Comment: Hmpf. That is what I thought when I saw it. Shit. Any chances with other databases? Is their any way around a fully features Rails backend?

Comment: No existing database will replicate from this. You have to build the thing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote database is static (data doesn't change), then it could work. You just have to find a way to iterate all records. Once you figured that out, the rest is simple as a pie: 1) query data; 2) store the response in a local database; 3) modify as you see fit.

If remote data changes, you'll have many troubles going this way (you'll have to re-sync in the same fashion every once in a while). What I'd do instead is create a local database with only new fields and a reference to the original piece of data. That is, when you request data from remote service, you also look if you have something in the local db and merge those two before processing the final result.

Comment: The remote database will change. Objects can be added, modified or deleted. Even they could change the attributes. What stays is the ID of the objects, I guess. From a programmer's point of view I would subclass/wrap their objects and add custom fields. Although, I need to retrieve updates from them from time to time - I do not want to forward a frontend end request to their database every time.

Comment: Well, it's up to you. You need a way to get/generate ids of all existing objects in their database so that you can go ahead and fetch the objects.

Comment: The iteration will be the hard part. I am even not sure whether I could request by ID. I had the idea to request quadrants of data since they all have geolocations.